# Why my router.post() allow just one operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working in a web project and I have a litle problem in my back-end side 
I'm sending data from front-end to back-end, and then make two operations :update the JSON file which is in a directory, and at the same time save the data in MongoDB, but only updating the JSON file works, I have to make as comment the updating code to see the data in MongoDB ,
Here is my code :

```
router.post('/', (req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body);

  var toSaveDb={
  name:req.body.name,
  age:req.body.age,

 }

 // operation 1 : save the imported data in MongoDB
 let mdata=new MachineData(toSaveDb);
 console.log(mdata);
 mdata.save();


  // operation2 : update the JSON file with imported data 
  fs.writeFile('C:/path/to/file', 
  JSON.stringify(toSaveDb),err=>{
    if(err){console.error(err);return;};
  }); 


 });
module.exports=router;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you missing an opening bracket ```(``` in the ```fs.writeFile...``` line?

Comment: I don't have a syntax error, I just made a mistake when I copied it ,I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like just a bug in the arguments to fs.writeFile. Change this:

```js
fs.writeFile('C:/path/to/file'), 
  JSON.stringify(toSaveDb),err=>{
    if(err){console.error(err);return;};
  });
```

to this:

```js
fs.writeFile("C:/path/to/file", JSON.stringify(toSaveDb), (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
});
```

Now it's correct, and [Prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAzAzgOgO4CcCW8AYvgDZwAUA5AMJID0ADgIYwAW9ME9qZcVAGgA6UITABSAZQDyAOUzoYBKAHN8qAJ4Uuk5gDc4AEQBGASmGj4uXAAIAvAD4bwEWLHqKca6eeuYbmEgodAhyTC9cCFxPbwBuPwDcOBgAV1woeMsxAF8-XKhTWJABEAhGGHxodGRQZmsIbAAFOoRqlGZSbGYNapLjXGYwAGtkyRYwfFVkJRS4ErYYAFtSAHU2Qjh0cbhJVsJ8PUINZHB0XpBJ9C8YRoGVReZkVA6rkoArdAAPACEB4dHmIs4AAZSZwJ4vOYgD6fSSTFTkACKKQg8AhpFeIBYuCuuBOxmYxjgpGKWOUMBW+AAJuxkAAOAAMJUYkSuKwGjBOLM2XgMpIAjij4Lcym0QMx0ABaKBwOBUuWkpKC-BJW7Me6PJDPDFQq6LfDTXCzEroeFIoXgrWQkowQmUmlsZAAJhtAzI8JoEEWDxOmwArKSUlcACqEtrazF6WYASSg8tgkjABHKAEE45IYBpyOirtlskA).

Comment: I don't have a syntax error, I just made a mistake when I copied it ,I did it exactly as you

Comment: OK. So mdata.save() must be asynchronous. Try calling fs.writeFile after mdata.save() resolves.

Comment: I did it,but it still the same thing !

Comment: Nothing ! I really don't understand why ! I'm beginer at Node js and I'm not very good in non-blocking functionality